# Laravel - catch all eloquent requests

Tags: php, laravel, events, eloquent

As we can read [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#events), we can listen the eloquent events and use it in the AppServiceProvider. It goes like this:

```
public function boot()
{
    User::creating(function ($user) {
        Log::create(['message' => 'create method']);
    });

    User::deleting(function ($user) {
        Log::create(['message' => 'delete method']);
    });
}
```

For all my eloquent models, I want to log in the database when it is created and who created it. This would mean that I need to copy paste this snippet 20 times and only change the `User::creating` part.

Is there a way that I can catch the eloquent events from all models and make something like this:

```
public function boot()
{
    AllModels::creating(function ($model) { // <--- something like this here?
        Log::create([
            'message' => 'create method',
            'model' => get_class($model) // <--- and then get the class name
        ]);

    AllModels::deleting(function ($user) {
       /***/
    }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$models = ['User', 'Post', 'Comment', ....];
foreach ($models as $model) {
    $model::creating(....);
    $model::deleting(....);
}
```

Similar approach worked for me (I used DI instead of facades though).

Another approach I found and bookmarked some time ago:

```
Event::listen(['eloquent.creating: *'], function() {
    ....
});
```